# React Native - state hook updates and it's re-rendering the component, but nothing shows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-state

so here's the code:

```js
export default () => {
    const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync().then((tmpAlbums) => {
            setAlbums(tmpAlbums);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <View>
            {albums && (
                <FlatList
                    data={albums}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
                    }}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    );
};
```

I'm sure that state updates because I logged it and it was updated, I already have the permissions and I've just removed it for simplicity. I've tried everything and yet, nothing shows on the component/screen.

Comment: The error doesn't seems to be here. Could you share your whole code, in https://codesandbox.io/ for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the `Text`.

Either do

```
{albums && (
   <FlatList
     data={albums}
     renderItem={({ item }) => {
       return (<Text>{item.title}</Text>)
     }}
   />
 )}
```

Or

```
{albums && (
  <FlatList
    data={albums}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>)
    )}
   />
 )}
```